# ASP.NET CORE WEB API authentication via Social Network

Tags: asp.net-core, social-networking, asp.net-core-webapi

I have to build WEB api application that can authenticate user via Socail network like Facebook.
I understand how it's happening in asp.net core mvc, but I have no idea how it's happening in Web API. I find resource that build LinkedIn authentication in Startup.cs with code like this

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
                LogoutPath = new PathString("/logout")
            });

            app.UseOAuthAuthentication(new OAuthOptions
            {
                // We need to specify an Authentication Scheme
                AuthenticationScheme = "LinkedIn",

                // Configure the LinkedIn Client ID and Client Secret
                ClientId = Configuration["linkedin:clientId"],
                ClientSecret = Configuration["linkedin:clientSecret"],

                // Set the callback path, so LinkedIn will call back to http://APP_URL/signin-linkedin
                // Also ensure that you have added the URL as an Authorized Redirect URL in your LinkedIn application
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-linkedin"),

                // Configure the LinkedIn endpoints                
                AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization",
                TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken",
                UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,email-address,picture-url)",

                Scope = { "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress" },

                Events = new OAuthEvents
                {
                    // The OnCreatingTicket event is called after the user has been authenticated and the OAuth middleware has
                    // created an auth ticket. We need to manually call the UserInformationEndpoint to retrieve the user's information,
                    // parse the resulting JSON to extract the relevant information, and add the correct claims.
                    OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                    {
                        // Retrieve user info
                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
                        request.Headers.Add("x-li-format", "json"); // Tell LinkedIn we want the result in JSON, otherwise it will return XML

                        var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        // Extract the user info object
                        var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                        // Add the Name Identifier claim
                        var userId = user.Value<string>("id");
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                        }

                        // Add the Name claim
                        var formattedName = user.Value<string>("formattedName");
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formattedName))
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, formattedName, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                        }

                        // Add the email address claim
                        var email = user.Value<string>("emailAddress");
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email, ClaimValueTypes.String,
                                context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                        }

                        // Add the Profile Picture claim
                        var pictureUrl = user.Value<string>("pictureUrl");
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("profile-picture", pictureUrl, ClaimValueTypes.String,
                                context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            app.Map("/logout", builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    // Sign the user out of the authentication middleware (i.e. it will clear the Auth cookie)
                    await context.Authentication.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                    // Redirect the user to the home page after signing out
                    context.Response.Redirect("/api/Account/LogOut");
                });
            });
            app.Map("/login", builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    // Return a challenge to invoke the LinkedIn authentication scheme
                    await context.Authentication.ChallengeAsync("LinkedIn", properties: new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/api/Account/Create" });
                });
            });
loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();
        //app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

As you can see in the end of the file there are two map methods. They are managing login and logout. So can you recomend me how to build my app in right way, or how can create two controller methods, that can do the same things. 
 Thank you, and sorry for my English

Comment: Any reason why you are writing your one when there is an existing in the ASP.NET Core Contribution repository https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn (https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn on nuget)?